# Silverlight 4 stackpanel fading in / out needed

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I would like to add an animation to my stack-panel. when the mouse is over it, the opacity has to be one. When the mouse is leaving it, the opacity decreases gradually.
Could you please help me.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Storyboard using timeline in Blend, I'm using Blend 4.

Fade In
select the stackpanel

1. Select Assets -> Behaviors -> drag and drop Changeproperty on the Stack Panel.
2. goto Objects and Timeline -> Select ChangeProperty under Stackpanel -> goto Properties select Trigger Event Name:MouseEnter -> Next in Common Property, PropertyName:Opacity -> Next in Animation Add Duration:00:00:0.5

repeat the same to Fade Out a little change.
PropertyName:Opacity Change the Value:0

That's works.
enjoy.